# Regular expressions for validating a mailing address

Tags: php, regex

I have strings like follow

```
field_zip_code:"48103"

taxonomy:88 field_zip_code:"48103"

taxonomy:88 field_state:"MI" field_zip_code:"48103"
```

From here i want to extract variable values like `48103,88,MI`

i need regular expressions in PHP,

Thanks in advance
Kamal

Comment: there's a way to write a regex that succeeds on the last string. do u want the regex to fail on the first two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use three regular expressions for the three fields you want

```
field_zip_code:"(\d+)"
taxonomy:(\d+)
field_state:"(\w+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper grammar to apply the regex to :(

Answer (score 0):

If the 3 fields are always ordered like this,

```
^(?:taxonomy:(\d+))?\s*(?:field_state:"([^"]+)")?\s*(?:field_zip_code:"([^"]+)")$
```

Otherwise, perform 3 matches as [@Otto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348496/regular-expressions-for-validating-a-mailing-address/2348539#2348539) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to also be thinking about non-standard zipcodes. 009HH, for example, is a valid ZIP in the US Postal Mail system.

Also, do think about Canadian zipcodes if your business needs to support them - they're in a radically different format.

Comment: Google is not the end-all-be-all. See this, for example: http://www.laonmap.com/zipcode/id_009HH.html

Comment: Nice try, but the "US Postal Mail system" system is only numbers: https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupAction_input.